# How to pass list of objects as parameter in function and then use object's attributes C#

Tags: c#, list

So that's my function:

```
public bool CheckUniqueName<T>(string newName, List<T> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (list[i].name == newName)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have this List of Planets: `private List<Planet> planetsList = new List<Planet>();`

BUT: I'm gonna use other Lists like `public List<Colony> ColonyList = new List<Colony>();` That's why I need `List<T>`

And class `Planet`:

```
class Planet
{
    ...
    public string name { get; }
    ... 
}
```

And I try this: `(some stuff) CheckUniqueName(name, planetsList)` in other class

As I get it, `List<T>` doesn't know about the `.name` attribute.

I tried to create another List and do something like this:

```
public bool CheckUniqueName<T>(string newName, List<T> list)
    {
        if (list is List<Planet>)
        {
            var newList = planetsList;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (list[i].name == newName)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It didn't work and same things with creating new List didn't work as well.

Comment: You need to derive from a base class that has the Name property common to every derived class

Comment: (or implement an interface, which has the `Name` property)

Comment: Note that your whole method could be replaced by `!list.Any(x => x.name == newname)` (or `list.All(x => x.Name != newName)`). Given this, I'm not sure it's worth having a whole separate method for this, and the problem goes away...

Comment: If you're doing different things with lists of different types of objects, write different methods. This is not what generics are for. Generics are for cases where you can do the *same* thing with different types for `T`. You can use a generic type constraints, in some cases. But the right way to write a method like this would be a common base class that has the desired property  or properties, and then write a method that takes `IEnumerable<WhateverBaseClass>` -- not generic at all. And as suggested above, you probably don't need to write any method, generic or otherwise.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot! That's very helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using generic constraints here:

```
public bool CheckUniqueName<T>(string newName, IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : INamed

    => !items.Any(i => (i.Name == newName));

public interface INamed
{
    public Name { get; }
}

public class Planet : INamed
{
    public Name { get; }

    public Plant(string name)
    { 
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Colony : INamed
{
    public Name { get; }

    public Colony(string name)
    { 
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't need to use generics.  It can just be `CheckUniqueName(string newName, IEnumerable<INamed> items)`

Comment: @juharr That's only true if you can guarantee that every implementation of `INamed` is a class, and not a struct.

Comment: @juharr You're right, I'm just trying to build a generic method as spec'd by the OP but maybe does he just need a common interface

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to pass a delegate which knows how to fetch the `name` property off any type you pass in:

```
public bool CheckUniqueName<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string newName, Func<T, string> nameSelector)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        string name = nameSelector(item);
        if (name == newName)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
CheckUniqueName(planetsList, "name", planet => planet.name);
```

Then your `name` property doesn't have to be called `name` -- it can be called whatever you want.

---

I wrote a long version of the `CheckUniqueName` method for clarity, but you could shorten it using linq:

```
public bool CheckUniqueName<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string newName, Func<T, string> nameSelector)
{
    return !items.Any(item => newName == nameSelector(item));
}
```

However once you go this far, you might as well discard the `CheckUniqueName` method entirely, and instead just write:

```
!plantsList.Any(x => x.name == "name");
```